# Is there a concept like include directory aliases?

Tags: c++, include, cmake, cross-platform, project

In a cross-platform project I make use of many third party libraries. I finally decided to include their source into my repository, to not need to download them again on every platform. This is is allowed by the licences.

To include headers from those libraries, I need to specify their file paths. Some libraries have them in `name/include/name/file.h` but generally, every library comes with a different directory structure.

I would like to include the headers in my code always in the form `#include "name/file.h"` where *name* is the name of the library. But I neither want to modify the directory structure of the libraries nor copy all headers into include directory of my desired structure.

Is there a way to define something like include directory aliases? For example, *Bullet Physics* has its headers in `bullet/src`, *Sqlite* has its headers directly in `sqlite` and *SFML* has them in `sfml/include/SFML`. I would like to specify something like this:

```
#alias "dependencies/bullet/src" "bullet"
#alias "dependencies/sqlite" "sqlite"
#alias "dependencies/sfml/include/SFML" "sfml"
```

So that `#include "sfml/System.hpp"` becomes equivalend to 
 `#include "dependencies/sfml/include/SFML/System.hpp"`.

The technique doesn't have to be in preprocessor stage. It could also be a CMake flag to generate projects in the right way, for example. However, I think compilers must be aware of this technique somehow, to make this possible.

Comment: You could add varying `-I` options from your build system?

Comment: No; the nearest approach is a collection of `-I` options on the command line.  Further, if you use SFML, they recommended notation is `#include "SFML/System.hpp"`; that's what you should write in your code.  Then you fix the compilation environment so that `-Idependencies/sfml/include` is included in the compilation, or you use symlinks (if they're portable enough) to manufacture sub-directories like `SFML` in the main directory that contains your project's headers.

Comment: The `-I` flag doesn't allow me to provide an alias. That would spam the include space and make it unnecessarily hard to find headers from a single given library.

Comment: No `-I` option will make `bullet/src/hdr.h` accessible as `bullet/hdr.h`

Comment: Create a dependencies directory containing soft links to the various include directories of the 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @MSalters Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @ruslo I'll read into this because it sounds interesting, but I imagine this could actually make things significantly more complicated.

Comment: @user2672165 I guess symlinks are not cross-platform. How could I overcome this?

Comment: For cross platform solution you could e.g. place an include file in the dependencies directory that would in turn include the final include files. Perhaps you could make use of pre-processor conditionals if the final path varies with platform. Maybe you could also get ideas from how others do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; the nearest approach is a collection of `-I` options on the command line.

Further, if you use SFML, the recommended notation is `#include "SFML/System.hpp"`; that's what you should write in your code.  Then you fix the compilation environment so that `-Idependencies/sfml/include` is included in the compilation, or you use symlinks (if they're portable enough) to manufacture sub-directories like `SFML` in the main directory that contains your project's headers.

When software packages like SFML are installed, the headers will be placed into a directory — normally `/usr/local/include` by default, and usually in a sub-directory under there.  That is, there would be a directory `/usr/local/include/SFML` which would contain the SFML headers.  The chances are the same is true of other software packages.  You should install these headers in some location under your build area so that the headers can be found as normal — you'll simply specify the base `include` directory under which the headers are found.  (Note: when you install the [Bullet Physics library](https://github.com/erwincoumans/bullet3), the headers are placed into a directory `.../include/bullet` with various sub-directories underneath that, so it too follows this convention.)

Doing otherwise means fighting the system, and when you fight the system, you end up losing.  It is harder work than simply going with the flow.

Comment: Why does I need to install Bullet to get the headers into one place? Of course, I need to build all libraries once per platform and build configuration. But headers shouldn't be affected by this, do they?

Comment: Not all libraries in my project follow the `include/name/` convention. Is there a tool to extract the first header file, and all those it includes recursively, to manually create that folder?

Comment: Which of your libraries when installed does not install the headers either in a directory similar to `/usr/local/include` or in a sub-directory under `/usr/local/include`? Those are the two 'standard' locations. With the first case, you're encouraged to write `#include "libheader.h"`; with the second, you're encouraged to write `#include "libname/libheader.h"`. I know of one system that doesn't follow that convention; it uses sub-directory `incl` instead of `include` (and version 1 pre-dated the convention). However, even that was fixable using an appropriate `-I/usr/software/incl` directory.

Comment: The libraries deviating from this directory structure are [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), and the header only library [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html). I may be missing something though, like it was with Bullet.

Comment: When configured with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/oss`, the zlib 1.2.8 build process installs two headers in `$HOME/oss/include` (`zlib.h` and `zconf.h`).  Therefore, if you write `#include "zlib.h"` and used `-I$HOME/oss/include` on the command lines, the headers would be picked up.  If you omitted `--prefix` from the configure, the code would have been placed under `/usr/local`.  I've not yet checked the other libraries, but I expect to find similar behaviour -- when installed, the headers are in an appropriate location in a `.../include` directory.

Comment: When configured with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/oss`, the libzip 0.11.2 build process installs one header in `$HOME/oss/include` (that's `zip.h`, which you should include with `#include <zip.h>`), and the other in `$HOME/oss/lib/libzip/include` (that's `zipconf.h`, which is included by `zip.h`).  Thus, with the raw `libzip` install, you would need to include `-I$HOME/oss/lib/libzip/include` as a command line option.  I regard that as a problem that I would solve that problem by making a file `$HOME/oss/include/zipconf.h` (on Unix, it would be a symlink; on Windows, probably a copy).

Comment: That may be correct from a Linux point of view. However, this is a cross-platform project, both for development and distribution. It's not that nice under Windows. (With just targeting Linux, I would just rely on a package manager instead of including library source into my repository.)

Comment: Since I don't do Windows development, I can't answer to the problems there, but I'd expect (perhaps naively) that the net result is equivalent.  Especially if you're using cmake to coordinate the builds, you should be able to get the idiosyncrasies resolved across platforms.

Comment: By the way, I just built Bullet Physics from source and haven't got a `include` directory. Are you sure it creates one?

Answer (score 5):

I was building everything in one build run (Not in packages)
I managed to do exactly what you want using Cmake by doing the following:

In the highest CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TEMP_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tempIncludes)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${TEMP_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(<TARGET_NAME> PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${TEMP_INCLUDE_DIR}>
)
```

This will create a folder in the binary directory (that is removed when you clean your project so it isn't modifying your actual folder structure and I am assuming you are NOT using in-source build)

Then in the CMakeLists.txt for the target library:

```
set(LIB_NAME <ThirdPartyLibraryName>)
set(INCLUDE_FOLDER <WhatEverThirdPartyIncludeDirectory>)
set(HEADER_FILES
    ${INCLUDE_FOLDER}/<Header1>.h
    ${INCLUDE_FOLDER}/<Header2>.h
)
file(COPY ${HEADER_FILES} DESTINATION ${TEMP_INCLUDE_DIR}/${LIB_NAME}/)
```

This will make a folder structure with all include files copied into standard directories that will allow you to use the `#include "name/file.h"` form you want.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no".

There are a few different options:

- Symlinks - set up your own "myincludes" directory, and then link all the relevant files to there, in their relative position.
- Use more complex -I options to your project.
- Write your own pre-preprocessor (which translates a given `#include` into the "actual file in the actual place", given some set of rules)
- Adjust the install directories of the respective projects.
- Don't do any of the above, and use the names as they appear on your actual filesystem.

I personally prefer the "don't do this" option. For one thing, moving/changing how files are included is more than likely to confuse some people, and third party code certainly won't be written this way, so you won't be able to use anyone else's code maintaining this style.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Including the libraries as they appear on the file system would be terrible since some libraries directly include their headers. So I would need to set my `dependencies` as include directory to get `#include "library/header.h"`. Doing this would inject all my dependencies into include space, also docs and other undesired files. Adjusting directories of other projects feels wrong and makes updating libraries more work but may be a possibility. Could you elaborate on what you mean with *more complex* `-I` options please?

Comment: I['m basically saying the same thing as Jonathan. If the concern is with Windows filesystem idiosyncrasies, then the problem is with the build/install for Windows, not to be fixed by adding more clutter in the source files that you compile.